# Matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation to iterate a list one time

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currently I'm working with a surface to be analyzed, 4000 40x40 frames. Mechanically it is a list of 4000 frames, which are a list of 40 lines, which are a list of 40 data points.

I'm using funcanimation to see how it changes over time, but I'm running into an issue. Basically at this point I have two questions:

1) How can I iterate through the frames one time, eventually to be used for saving it?

2) Why does my current code give me a spinning beachball if I try to exit out of the animation?

```
def update_fig(*args):
  global currentNum, numSurfaces
  currentNum += 1
  if currentNum < numSurfaces:
    print(currentNum)
  im.set_array(testClass.surfaceList[currentNum])
  return im,
    else:
      pass


def updatefig(*args):
  global currentNum, numSurfaces
  currentNum += 1
  if currentNum > numSurfaces - 1:
    currentNum = 0
  print currentNum
  im.set_array(testClass.surfaceList[currentNum])
  return im,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, frames=4000, interval=0.5, repeat=False, blit=False)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Comment: There are two reasons to ignore the second question: 1. The two questions are unrelated. Stackoverflow is about asking specific questions. If you have two questions, ask two questions.
2. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can save the figure by looping over frames before starting the animation.

```
def updatefig(i):
    im.set_array(testClass.surfaceList[i])

for i in range(4000):
    updatefig(i)
    plt.savefig("frame{}.png".format(i))

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, frames=4000, interval=0.5, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

You can also use the animation to save the figures

```
def updatefig(i):
    im.set_array(testClass.surfaceList[i])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, frames=4000, interval=0.5, repeat=False)
ani.save("frames.png", writer="imagemagick")
plt.show()
```

This second approach only works for png images and requires imagemagick to be installed.